# bootstrap form input accept text only

Tags: jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

Trying to create a contact form and realized that in the name input box, any character (ie. ~ / % @ # and etc.) and numbers can be entered.

```
<form>
  <label class="control-label" for="name">Full Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" maxlength="30">
</form>
```

Is there a bootstrap class or jQuery function that I can add to **restrict** the *name* input box to only the 26 alphabet? (Or at least no numeric value allowed...) Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with some jquery. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/ka52kdLv/2

```
<input class="alphaonly">
```

```js
$('.alphaonly').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^a-z ]/g,'') ); }
);
```

Or for a beautiful solution you can take a look for some validation libs.

Comment: thanks a lot Dan for your input! This does work, but I would like something more beautiful:) When you say validation libs do you mean bootstrap validation states- http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation?

Comment: @DDan how can I still allow the space bar in the input with your jQuery?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something like validate.js
Updated to allow sapce: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/ka52kdLv/2/